# How to check previous ranking of a website in search engine?

Tags: ranking, google-ranking

I re-built the website in 2014 and I want to know if website ranking is improved after I built.

Is there a way in which I can see previous ranking position of website and current ranking position of the website in terms of Google ranking?

Comment: Short answer? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to analyze if your SEO has improved is by comparing the metrics. If you see an increase in the number of overall visitors per day or lesser bounce rate or more time spent per page or per session, your SEO is headed in the right direction.

**There's no tool which can give you the rank of your website**. 
You can query for the targeted keywords and see for yourself in the search results where you land.